# Cms no route page not working. Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, 404-page

A page with an invalid url should redirect to a page not found, but it throws an error

> TypeError: Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::processRequest(): Argument #2 ($actionInstance) must be of type Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface, Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect\Interceptor given, called in vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php on line 147 and defined in vendor\magento\framework\App\FrontController.php:177

[image]

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check any third-party modules that may influence router selection (using plugins or own router), which may result in an error. Try disabling all suspicious modules and check the result (don't forget to run `setup:di:compile` first).

Analyze the `di.xml` files within these modules for any entries associated with the `routerList` argument. This will provide insight into the sequence and any custom routers that might be active.

Check routers list (and it's order) in the `Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::dispatch()` method (using xDebug or other debug method):

Inside the `dispatch()` method, you will find a loop that goes through all the routers and tries to match the request to a specific router. This loop is where Magento tries each router in sequence until it finds one that can handle the request:

```
foreach ($this->_routerList as $router) {
    $actionInstance = $router->match($request); // Main debugging point!
    if ($actionInstance) {
        $request->setDispatched(true);
        $this->response->setNoCacheHeaders();
        if ($actionInstance instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction) {
            $result = $actionInstance->dispatch($request);
        } else {
            $result = $actionInstance->execute();
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Seems like some custom router returns incorrect instance.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the below commands. Let me know if it's works

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod 777 var/ generated/ pub/static/ pub/media/
```